# React form: Leading text cannot be in the same line of the input field

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm new to React so don't know where does this problem come from.

I'm using ReactModal imported from "react-modal" as the container of my form.

And the leading text cannot be in the same line as the input field.

I think this might be caused by in-built style from ReactModal?

Here's the code snippet

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactModal from "react-modal";

export default function GitModal() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);

  const handleOpenModal = () => {
    setState(true);
  };

  const handleCloseModal = () => {
    setState(false);
  };

  const data = {
    name: "HarryPotter",
    type: "book",
    date: "20220202",
    description: "bought in UK",
    specialAttribute: "VerySpecial",
    itemID: "123123",
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOpenModal}>Trigger Modal</button>
      <ReactModal
        isOpen={state}
        contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
        data={data}
      >
        <form id="login">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input
              type="text"
              className="input-field"
              required
              defaultValue={data.name}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Description:
            <input
              type="text"
              className="input-field"
              required
              defaultValue={data.description}
            />
          </label>
          <button type="reset">Save Changes</button>
        </form>
        <button onClick={handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
      </ReactModal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here's the effect of the code: the 'Name' and 'HarryPotter' is not in same line
[image]

And I want it to be like:

Name: HarryPotter  (in same line)

Comment: Normally, you would want to wrap the label and input in its own tags and place them into a container like a div or fieldset. And with some CSS you can make them align each other nicely :)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with `react-modal`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do the following on your css:

```
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

and your `<label/>` tag is wrapping the input as well. the correct is as it follows:

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Name:
 </label>

 <input
   type="text"
   className="input-field"
   required
   value="Harry Potter"
 />
```

Comment: I found that there's other css affecting my input field with className="input-field". But your answer still helps, thanks!